# OpenCv Visual C++ 2010 Express problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

Hi I am trying to run the code below but having problems with the cvCreateFileCapture function.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace std;


int main( int argc, char** argv ) { 
cvNamedWindow( "Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
// CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromAVI( argv[1] ); // either one will work

CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "test.avi");
IplImage* frame;
while(1) {
    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    if( !frame ) break;
    cvShowImage( "Example2", frame );
    char c = cvWaitKey(33);
    if( c == 27 ) break;
}
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow( "Example2" );
```

}

Initially I was getting an error about a missing msvcr90d.dll  file. I had to download vs 2008 and change the platform toolset configuration settings. After I did this I got the error below. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I bet `cvCreateFileCapture()` is failing because it didn't found the file. You just don't know because you are not checking the return of the function.

It returns `NULL` if it can't load the video file.

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("test.avi");
if (capture == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "!!! cvCreateFileCapture failed !!!" << std::endl;
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I think that when you execute the application from within VStudio it will try to find the video on the same directory as your source code files. One way to make sure the app will load the video file, it's to put the video in the Debug (or Release) folder and execute your application from there, manually. Both video and app must be in the same directory.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, it is not returning NULL anymore. Before it finishes cvCreateFileCapture the error message pops up.

Comment: Since you installed VS 2008 because of OpenCV, shouldn't you be using it? The error msg clearly shows that you are still using VS2010. **OpenCV 2.3** has a package for **VS2008**: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.3/

Comment: and **OpenCV 2.2** has a package for **VS2010**: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.2/ Pick the one you like.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what openCv is, but if memory serves me, msvcr90d.dll is the debug dll for VC++2008. 
Have you checked your project's configuration and properties to see what mode and what dlls it is using/importing ?